# Android - Cordova version code issue

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, trigger.io

This is quite a weird one.

Basically, I decided to switch from using [trigger.io](https://trigger.io/) to using cordova to build and compile my app (using ionic framework).

Everything is fine if I build an unsigned and unaligned app, but for production I have to sign and align the apk in order to upload it on the play store.

I have signed and aligned the apk properly, but when I tried to upload the apk, I got this error:

> Your APK version code needs to be greater than 1457108319

Now, I read a couple of answers here on stack overflow saying that I just need to add this line in my project config.xml file:

```
<widget id="com.***********" android-versionCode="1457108319" version="5.0.0"
```

but the problem is that if I had this line of code, then gradle fails and I get this error:

> Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args:
>   /s,/c,"c:\src\app-v5\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildRelease -b
>   c:\src\app-v5\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
>   -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"

Hovewer, if I change the versionCode to a 6 digit code instead of 10, I get no error, but again, I can't upload it to the store because the versionCode number is less than the app already released.

How can I solve this? I really have no idea what to do.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually resolved this. I had to add to my config.xml file the following (in `<widget>, right after version)`:

> android-versionCode="{this needs to be replaced, in my case, by the
>   current timestamp "

The downside is that I have to remember to put the new timestamp everytime for now.

I will, at some point, write some kind of script to do this for me.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem since updating to latest Cordova CLI (6.3.1) and latest android platform for cordova (5.2.2).

My old build had the following:
versionCode: 69000
from the config.xml file:

My new buid:
versionCode: 7000
from the config.xml file:

so when I upload the signed APK to the PlayStore I get the same error you had:

the problem is that 7000 is < to 69000

The issue comes from the gradle script (in platforms/android/build.gradle) which from what I understand generates the versionCode from what he finds in your config.xml.

Looks like it is missing some multiplication by 100 somewhere:

so far here is what can be done:
1: instead of using 0.70 as version number use 0.700
2: specify the versionCode in the config.xml file :

it worked for me in both cases.

Hope it helps.